# Problema con el open graph

Tags: html

Tengo un problema que no logró resolver con respecto al open graph de mi página. En un primer momento si lograba visualizarlo cuando compartía el link por whatsapp por ejemplo pero luego dejé de visualizarlo y no puedo entender si hay algún error en el meta o algo que modifiqué sin darme cuenta. Les dejo el código para ver si pueden ayudarme. Gracias

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="es">

<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA_Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <meta name="author" content="Rocio Traba">
    <meta name="keywords" content="Developer, web, product, design, ux, ui, desarrollo ">
    <meta name="description" content="Somos una product factory que diseña y desarrolla soluciones digitales eficientes según las necesidades del cliente de manera ágil, iterativa y de alto impacto en sus modelos de negocio." >
    <meta property="og:url" content="folcode.netlify.app" />
    <meta property="og:title" content="Folcode" />
    <meta property="og:image" content="https://pbs.twimg.com/profile_images/1382391091794751489/F-wZ7N7u_400x400.jpg" />
    <meta property="og:site_name" content="Folcode" />
    <meta property="og:type" content="website" />
    <meta property="og:description"
        content="Somos una product factory que diseña y desarrolla soluciones digitales eficientes según las necesidades del cliente de manera ágil, iterativa y de alto impacto en sus modelos de negocio." />
        <title>FOLCODE | Juntos rompemos nuestros límites</title>
    <link rel="shortcut icon" href=./img/favicon.ico type="image/x-icon">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="./css/compilacionCss.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="./css/lightslider.css">
    <script type="text/javascript" src="./js/jquery.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="./js/lightslider.js"></script>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://use.fontawesome.com/releases/v5.15.4/css/all.css"
        integrity="sha384-DyZ88mC6Up2uqS4h/KRgHuoeGwBcD4Ng9SiP4dIRy0EXTlnuz47vAwmeGwVChigm" crossorigin="anonymous">
    <link rel="preconnect" href="https://fonts.googleapis.com">
    <link rel="preconnect" href="https://fonts.gstatic.com" crossorigin>
    <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Jost:wght@500&display=swap" rel="stylesheet">
</head>
```

Comment: Por qué tienes todos repetido ? Es una pregunta... Nada no debe está repetidos... La etiqueta `!DOCTYPE`, `head`, y todos los link

Comment: Pegué dos veces el código en stack overflow pero revise mi index y aparece una sola vez.